# CPython 2.7 + Java

Tags: java, python, macos, python-2.7, cpython

My major program is written in Python 2.7 (on Mac) and need to leverage some function which is written in a Java 1.8, I think CPython cannot import Java library directly (different than Jython)?

If there is no solution to call Java from CPython, could I integrate in this way -- wrap the Java function into a Java command line application, Python 2.7 call this Java application (e.g. using `os.system`) by passing command line parameter as inputs, and retrieve its console output?

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you have lot of dependcieis on Java/JVM, you can consider using `Jython`.
- If you would like to develop a scalable/maintainable application, consider using microservices and keep Java and Python components separate.
- If your call to Java is simple and it is easy to capture the output and failure, you can go ahead with this running the system command to invoke Java parts.

Comment: Thanks Sivasubramaniam, good point. For "running the system command", do you mean running `os.system` in Python?

Comment: @LinMa Yes. You can use `command` module which is very handy. For example `commands.getstatusoutput('ls -l')`

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 0):

A number of open source projects have been written to enable calling Java from CPython, depending on your needs.

- [Pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Py4J](https://www.py4j.org/)
- [JPype forked](https://github.com/originell/jpype) (original JPype hasn't been updated in years)
- [jpy](https://github.com/bcdev/jpy)